# Possible multiple returned matches joined to a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I am not even sure how to ask this question but here's my situation.  I use Plex to stream movies at home.  I've built a database which I translate to a webpage that I use as an index.  With in this database I have a few tables.  The main one is called movie_list.  1 of the fields is called Rating which has an association table called assc_movie_genre which simply stores the movie id generated from the main table and a genre id which is read from another association table.  There can be multiple movie Id's that are the same which match a Genre, for instance let's say The Matrix falls under the category Action and Sci Fi there will be 2 entries for MovieId each on matching the corresponding genre code.  Anyways, my question is I need a query (if possible) that can join all genres to the appropriate row.  Right now I have the following query

```
SELECT a.`Title`,a.`Year`,b.`Rating` FROM movie_list a, assc_rating b WHERE b.`Id` = a.`Rating
```

But would need to expand it to I guess join the multiple genres that match.  I hope that all makes sense.

Thanks in advance

**Update**

Thanks to your help I am also there.  Here is my current query

```
SELECT a.Title, c.Rating, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.GenreId ORDER BY b.GenreId) 
AS Genres FROM assc_movie_genre b, movie_list a, assc_rating c 
WHERE a.Id = b.MovieId AND a.Rating = c.Id group by a.Title 
ORDER BY a.Title;
```

But the issue remains where I am just getting the GenreId instead of the genre name.  I would assume I need to put a select in there somewhere so that it is pulling the name from the assc_genres tables just not 100% sure where.

Here's what the current output looks like

```
Title                   Rating               Genres
28 Days Later...        R                    11,16,17
```

The concat works great and I'm so close.  Thanks again

**Update**

Here are the queries to create my tables, you can get the structure from here (obviously)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assc_genres` (
`Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Genre` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assc_movie_genre` (
`MovieId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`GenreId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
KEY `FK_assc_movie_genre_movie_list` (`MovieId`),
KEY `FK_assc_movie_genre_assc_genres` (`GenreId`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_assc_movie_genre_movie_list` FOREIGN KEY (`MovieId`) REFERENCES `movie_list` (`Id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_assc_movie_genre_assc_genres` FOREIGN KEY (`GenreId`) REFERENCES `assc_genres` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assc_rating` (
`Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Rating` char(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assc_status` (
`Id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`Status` char(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `movie_list` (
`Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Title` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Year` year(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000',
`Rating` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Folder` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
UNIQUE KEY `Title_Year` (`Title`,`Year`),
KEY `FK_movie_list_assc_rating` (`Rating`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_movie_list_assc_rating` FOREIGN KEY (`Rating`) REFERENCES `assc_rating` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=614 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: What do you do with the result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure as well if this is what you are asking, but you can join all 3 tables to get the data like

```
SELECT a.`Title`,
a.`Year`,
b.`Rating` 
FROM movie_list a
JOIN assc_movie_genre c ON a.Id = c.movie_id
JOIN assc_rating b ON b.`Id` = c.genre_id;
```

Per your comment you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` like

```
SELECT a.`Title`,
a.`Year`,
b.`Rating`,
xx.genre_list 
FROM movie_list a
JOIN ( select movie_id, genre_id, group_concat(genre) as genre_list 
from assc_movie_genre 
group by movie_id) xx ON a.Id = xx.movie_id
JOIN assc_rating b ON b.`Id` = xx.genre_id;
```

You can modify your query like

```
SELECT a.Title, c.Rating, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.`Genre` ORDER BY d.`Genre`) AS Genres 
FROM movie_list a
JOIN assc_movie_genre b ON a.Id = b.MovieId
JOIN assc_rating c ON a.Rating = c.Id 
JOIN `assc_genres` d ON b.`GenreId` = d.Id
group by a.Title 
ORDER BY a.Title;
```

Comment: That's close, but some movies have multiple genres, is there a way to join all the genres in the same row?

Comment: Yes absolutely using `group_concat()` and `group by` but without seeing your table structure I can atmost give a blind answer.

Comment: @EdDunn, look into the edit in answer if that helps.

Comment: Yes, that looks great. I will give it a shot. Thanks again

Comment: @EdDunn, me too not 100% sure unless you post the table structure. don't know from which table to pull the column. Post your table structure.

Comment: Updated the above, added my create statements

Comment: You're a life saver!  Thank you so much